# BoostPython and CMake

Tags: python, c++, cmake, boost-python

I have successfully followed [this](https://shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/) example for how to connect C++ and python. It works fine when I use the given `Makefile`. When I try to use `cmake` instead, it does not go as well.

C++ Code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<greet()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
# location of the Python header files
PYTHON_VERSION = 27
PYTHON_DOT_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_DOT_VERSION)
# location of the Boost Python include files and library
BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# compile mesh classes
TARGET = hello_ext
$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python-py$(PYTHON_VERSION) -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_DOT_VERSION)/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython$(PYTHON_DOT_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so
$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp
```

When I compile this I get a `.so` file that can be included in the script

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myname/Code/Trunk/TestBoostPython/build/')
import libhello_ext_lib as hello_ext

print(hello_ext.greet())
```

I really want to use `cmake` instead of a manually written `Makefile` so I wrote this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
PROJECT(hello_ext)

# Find Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python-py27)

set(PYTHON_DOT_VERSION 2.7)
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE /usr/include/python2.7)
set(PYTHON_LIBRARY /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lrt -O3")

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBNAME hello_ext_lib)

add_library(${LIBNAME} SHARED src/hello_ext.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/hello_ext.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} -lpython2.7 -fPIC)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${LIBNAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} -lpython2.7 -fPIC -shared)
```

Here I currently type the `Python-paths` by hand but I have also tried using `fin_package(PythonLibs)` without success.

The program compiles fine and executes when I run the executable file in `../bin/`. However, when I run the python script I get always:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibhello_ext_lib)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226001/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-initfizzbuzz) which says this can happen if the `lib` and the `executable` have different names. Which indeed is the case, but how can I obtain the `.so` with correct name?

I also tried to not compile the executable but only the library. That did also not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)` creates an init function "inithello_ext", which should correspond to a module "hello_ext". But you are trying to import "libhello_ext_lib".

Give the module the same name as the filename. E.g. `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libhello_ext_lib)`.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes it simple.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with Boost.Python.