# ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function Naming is correct

Tags: python, c++, cmake

While trying to build python bindings with C, I have the following

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
#define MOD_ERROR NULL
#define MOD_INIT(name) PyObject* PyInit_##name(void)
#define MOD_RETURN(val) val
#else
#define MOD_ERROR
#define MOD_INIT(name) extern "C" void init##name(void)
#define MOD_RETURN(val)
#endif
```

My so's name is visualizer.so

and this error is produced.

I also call

MOD_INIT(visualizer)

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226001/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-initfizzbuzz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initfizzbuzz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226001/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-initfizzbuzz)