# How to fix 'ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)' error in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, import, module

I'm running a code on deep learning, which uses the opencv module, by running `python main.py` (contains `import cv2` statement), but always get the error `'ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)'`.

I've tried to reinstall my anaconda and create new virtual environments, but all got the same result. This problem really confuses me a lot and I've googled for many related problems, none of them works. I think the problem is something related to the environment and has nothing to do with the code, because I got the same result by simply run `import cv2` in python prompt. The more confusing thing is that, even after I remove the opencv module, I also get the same problem, but not a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Does anyone can give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found one possible reason of this error.
Recently I was configuring the caffe environment on one server, I downloaded the source code of opencv-2.4.13 and compiled manually, added `/usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/build/lib` to `$PYTHONPATH`, and caffe worked well. After that, when I entered one of my virtual environment using `conda activate py35`, which uses python3.5, tried `import cv2` in the python prompt, got the error above.

I'm not sure but I think the cause of the error is opencv-2.4.13 compiles a python2 interface so it can't be imported by python3. Python imports packages by searching the directories listed in sys.path, where `$PYTHONPATH` is in the second place after the current working directory ([This](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html) is a great article introduces the mechanism of python finding packages). So when we enter the py35 environment, **python will first look for `$PYTHONPATH` and find the opencv installed on the root directory instead of finding the opencv in the virtual environment** using `conda install opencv-python`.

So there are two solutions of this problem:

1. Use python2 instead.
2. Remove `/usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/build/lib` from `$PYTHONPATH`.

which all work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar post, might help:
[ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initfizzbuzz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226001/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-initfizzbuzz)

Could you provide info on how you installed the CV module?

Comment: I've read that post before, but it seems doesn't work for me. I've tried `conda install opencv` and `pip install opencv-python`, but all return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was caused by the `cv2.so` file in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`. After I deleted the file and use command `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`, it worked for python3.